# How to initialize account without discriminator in Anchor

Tags: anchor

Is there a way to create and initialize an account in Anchor without a discriminator?

I tried testing with an `initialize` instruction that makes a CPI to system program to create an account and then deserialize/serialize the data for new account. It seems to work, but wondering if there's a simpler way.

```
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    let space = 32;
    let lamports = Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(space as usize);

    let ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(
        &ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
        &ctx.accounts.user.key(),
        lamports,
        space,
        &ctx.program_id,
    );

    anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke(
        &ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;

    let mut account = User::try_from_slice(&ctx.accounts.user.data.borrow()).unwrap();

    account.user = ctx.accounts.payer.key();
    account.serialize(&mut *ctx.accounts.user.data.borrow_mut())?;

    msg!("Public Key: {}", account.user.to_string());
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is rougly how you initialize accounts with Native and similar to what Anchor's `init` macro does under the hood. I don't think there is a simpler way, but also note that you will not be able to deserialize this account from the client side by default because Anchor always assumes you have the 8 byte discriminator up-front.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to skip the Anchor discriminator? If you want to use the same account struct in different anchor programs you can do something like:

```
let account_data = ctx.accounts.rate_program_state.try_borrow_data()?;
let mut account_data_slice: &[u8] = &account_data;
let rate_state = RateState::try_deserialize_unchecked(&mut account_data_slice)?;
```

The 8byte discriminator is still there, created during initialization, but you can use the account struct without checking it.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code that looks very similar to this but its not working. What I'm trying to do is do a CPI "invoke_signed" and have the &[accounts] parameter of "invoke_signed" be the accounts that i get from Anchor's Context.

```
pub fn create_ad(
        ctx: Context<CreateAdAccount>,
        ad_name: String,
        link: String,
        time: String,
        money: String,
        approved_providers: Vec<Pubkey>,
        status: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Adding Ad...");
        msg!("Account Name: {}", ad_name);

        let new_ad = &mut ctx.accounts.ad;
        new_ad.discriminator = "ad".to_string();
        new_ad.is_initialized = true;
        new_ad.name = ad_name;
        new_ad.link = link;
        new_ad.time = time;
        new_ad.money = money;
        new_ad.approved_providers = approved_providers.clone();
        new_ad.status = status;

        let program_id = Pubkey::from_str("HB8LMbzurJuJvdEXNkTb1oetqohVb4PRPdbGGQCUGSY5").unwrap();

        for (index, provider_pubkey) in approved_providers.iter().enumerate() {
            let provider_ad_relation_account_info = &ctx.remaining_accounts[index];
            let new_ad_pubkey = new_ad.key();

            let seeds = &[
                "relation".as_ref(),
                provider_pubkey.as_ref(),
                new_ad_pubkey.as_ref(),
            ];

            let (provider_ad_pda, bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(seeds, &program_id);

            if provider_ad_pda != *provider_ad_relation_account_info.key {
                msg!("Invalid PDA for provider");
                return Ok(());
            }

            let account_len = 100;
            let rent = Rent::get()?;
            let rent_lamports = rent.minimum_balance(account_len);

            invoke_signed(
                &system_instruction::create_account(
                    ctx.accounts.signer.key,
                    provider_ad_relation_account_info.key,
                    rent_lamports,
                    account_len.try_into().unwrap(),
                    &program_id,
                ),
                &[
                    ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                    provider_ad_relation_account_info.clone(),
                    ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                ],
                &[&[
                    "relation".as_ref(),
                    provider_pubkey.as_ref(),
                    new_ad_pubkey.as_ref(),
                    &[bump_seed],
                ]],
            )?;

            msg!("unpacking state account");
            let mut account_data = try_from_slice_unchecked::<ProviderAdRelationState>(
                &provider_ad_relation_account_info.data.borrow(),
            ).unwrap();
            msg!("borrowed account data");

            account_data.discriminator = "relation".to_string();
            account_data.provider = *provider_pubkey;
            account_data.ad = new_ad_pubkey;
            account_data.state = 0; // PENDING

            msg!("serializing account");
            account_data
                .serialize(&mut &mut provider_ad_relation_account_info.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;
            msg!("state account serialized");
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Everything looks good so far, but when i try to compile i get this.

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> /src/lib.rs:92:21
   |
38 |         ctx: Context<CreateAdAccount>,
   |         ---
   |         |
   |         has type `anchor_lang::context::Context<'_, '_, '_, '_, CreateAdAccount<'2>>`
   |         has type `anchor_lang::context::Context<'_, '_, '_, '1, CreateAdAccount<'_>>`
...
92 |                     ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'2` must outlive `'1`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of the type `anchor_lang::prelude::Signer<'_>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant
   = note: the struct `anchor_lang::prelude::Signer<'info>` is invariant over the parameter `'info`
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance
```

Im not super familiar with lifetimes and Rust in general. I would like to know what i can do to get around getting this error. And also what is causing it in the first place.

Thank you